# Rundeck: How do I successfully enable the RSS feed?

Tags: rss, rundeck

I am using Rundeck Community edition on Windows. I want to enable the RSS feature so that I can present the data on a web dashboard. I have enabled rss in rundeck-config.properties:

```
#rss.enabled if set to true enables RSS feeds that are public (non-authenticated)
#rss.enabled=false
rss.enabled=true
```

I then restarted the JVM and can see that's it enabled correctly:

```
[2020-03-04 11:27:21.572]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Starting Rundeck 3.2.1-20200113 (2020-01-13) ...
[2020-03-04 11:27:21.572]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] using rdeck.base config property: C:/rundeck
[2020-03-04 11:27:21.588]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] loaded configuration: C:\rundeck\etc\framework.properties
[2020-03-04 11:27:21.635]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] **RSS feeds enabled**
[2020-03-04 11:27:21.635]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Using builtin realm authentication
[2020-03-04 11:27:21.635]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Preauthentication is disabled
[2020-03-04 11:27:21.697]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Rundeck is ACTIVE: executions can be run.
[2020-03-04 11:27:21.697]  WARN BootStrap --- [           main] The JVM default encoding is not UTF-8: windows-1252, you may not see output as expected for multibyte locales. Specify -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in the JVM options.
[2020-03-04 11:27:21.901]  WARN BootStrap --- [           main] [Development Mode] Usage of H2 database is recommended only for development and testing
[2020-03-04 11:27:22.057]  INFO BootStrap --- [           main] Rundeck startup finished in 880ms
Grails application running at http://myserver:4440 in environment: production
[2020-03-04 11:27:27.721] ERROR SetUserInterceptor --- [qtp499085946-36] Unauthenticated API request
[2020-03-04 11:27:27.752] ERROR AuthorizationInterceptor --- [qtp499085946-36] (unauthenticated) UNAUTHORIZED for menu/apiExecutionsRunningv14
[2020-03-04 11:27:41.433] DEBUG GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter --- [qtp499085946-40] Request is to process authentication
[2020-03-04 11:27:41.762] DEBUG GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter --- [qtp499085946-40] Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@880103f9: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@724e14b9: Username: myuser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: admin,user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 10.x.x.x; SessionId: node01b80jsnk95hit1hxoo2gz3q3dt2; Granted Authorities: admin, user
[2020-03-04 11:28:29.955] ERROR SetUserInterceptor --- [qtp499085946-34] Unauthenticated API request
...
```

However, when browsing the Activity page, there is no indication the feed is active, regardless of the filter critieria applied. The documentation states "If configured, an RSS icon provides a link to an RSS view of the events that match the current filtering criteria." [Source](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/08-activity.html#rss-link)

How do I successfully enable the RSS feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a lost icon (should be fixed on the next release) I tested under 3.0.X and works OK. On 3.2.3, you can use the link directly after set the feature and works:

```
http://your-rundeck-host:4440/feed/index?projFilter=YourProject
```

EDIT: Follow the issue [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5855).

Comment: Excellent response again. Thanks MegaDrive68k. Accessing the URL as stated provides the correct data.